# Android Library about override Resource

Tags: android, svg, vector, drawable

If I create a Library and add normal drawable int drawable-xxhdpi, then add Resource file with the same name at the app.the app's Reasource will replace the library's Resource, just like:

[image]

But if I use the svg resource,It won't replace the library's Resource,like:

[image]

How to replace the vector drawable?

Comment: I may be wrong,but according to your second pic the vector drawable you are trying to generate is not in "drawable xxhdpi" and considering the first pic the folder above it is of the "drawable" hence it is showing in the drawable directory after being built

Comment: the "ic_picture_loading.xml" all in the "drawable" folder. just the picture is hard to show

Comment: Have you put ic_picture_loading.xml in drawable-xxhdpi and checked?

Comment: whatevet put the ic_picture_loading.xml in which drawable,It don't work for every device,just put in drawable-anydpi-v21 can work for v21+

Answer (score 8):

During the build, vector drawables from the library are placed in the **drawable-anydpi-v21** folder.

Since this will take precedent on all v21+ devices, you need to move your app drawable to the same folder if you want it to override the library resource.

For pre-v21, you need to set `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` on the library and the app, and place the vector drawable in the **drawable** folder.

Comment: but it just useful for v21,how to support the pre-v21? I found the folder build/res/merged 'drawable-v4' is the library picture.

Comment: And the library will auto build vector drawables to drawable-v4,but why app won't?

Comment: For pre-v21, you need to set `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` on the library and the app, and place the vector drawable in the **drawable** folder.

Comment: If I add this on the library,It can'g generate drawable-v4,then throw that can't find picture error.But just add this in the app,It can't replace the library drawable.

Comment: I think the vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true just work for pre-studio.Now it can work by default.

Comment: what version of the support library are you using?

Comment: 25.0.0 the newest

Comment: so you have copies of the drawable in the **drawable** and **drawable-anydpi-v21** folders and have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` on both app and lib and it throws a "can't find picture error"?

Comment: yes.Just because the library can't generate the support drawable-v4,then throw "If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way."

Comment: I found something interesting.If I don't add useSupportLibrary at the library,It will generate the support drawable-v4, opposite it will generate.Then whether or not you add useSupportLibrary at the app,the library's vector will generate support-v4 drawable.Now If you add useSupportLibrary at the app, the library's vector also generate v4,But the app's vector won't generate v4!!!!Then you remove the useSupportLibrary at the app,the app will generate two type of vector support folder like "drawable-mdpi" and 'drawable-mdpi-v4".